# Error al utilizar GROUP BY

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-10g

Si alguien puede ayudarme, siempre me da este error:

> ORA-00979: no es una expresión GROUP BY
>   00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"

Necesito que en la columna `SDESERROR` se concatenen la descripcion del error cuando vienen mas de 2 codigos de errores.

Ya le he intetando agregar todas las columnas llamadas en  la query y en la subquery y nada.

```
SELECT  AU.sregist   AS sregist , --numero de la placa 
    CL.SCLIENAME AS SPOLICY , -- NOMBRECANAL,     
    S.SDESCRIPT AS SSALEPOINT,
    AU.NPOLICY AS N_POLESP_COMP, 
    AU.npremium AS NPRIMA,
    AU.SCLIENT AS NCOD_CLIENTE, 
    PC.SCLIENAME AS CONTRATANTE,
    AU.dstartdate AS D_STARTDATE, 
    AU.dexpirdat AS D_EXPIRDAT, 
    AU.NPOLICY AS NPOLICY,
    PLOG.DCOMPDATE AS NFECHA_REGISTRO,
    SUBSTR(CL.SCLIENAME,1,60)  AS S_CLIENAME,
    PLOG.SCOD_ERROR AS NSCOD_ERROR,
    E.SDESERROR AS DESERROR,
    RTRIM(XMLAGG(xmlelement(e, E.SDESERROR||'|')).extract('//text()'), '|') as SDESERROR,
    CASE WHEN PLOG.SCOD_ERROR IS NULL AND PLOG.NDIGIT_VERIF>=0 THEN 'ENVIADO' 
    WHEN TRIM(PLOG.SCOD_ERROR) IN('20001','20002') THEN 'ENVIADO' ELSE 'NO ENVIADO' END AS STRANSFERSTATUS, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY AU.dstartdate DESC ) ROWNUMBER,
    COUNT(*) OVER() ROWTOTAL
    FROM AUTO AU
    INNER JOIN pol_distribution@DBL_TIME_PRTCANAL.PROTECTA.DOM P ON AU.NPOLICY = P.npolesp_comp 
    INNER JOIN SALE_POINT@DBL_TIME_PRTCANAL.PROTECTA.DOM S ON S.NNUMPOINT=P.NNUMPOINT 
    INNER JOIN POLICY@DBL_TIME_PRTCANAL.PROTECTA.DOM PO ON PO.NPOLICY=S.NPOLICY 
    INNER JOIN CLIENT@DBL_TIME_PRTCANAL.PROTECTA.DOM CL ON CL.SCLIENT=PO.SCLIENT 
    INNER JOIN pv_client_soat PC ON PC.SCLIENT = AU.SCLIENT AND PC.NPOLICY=AU.NPOLICY 
    LEFT JOIN PV_APESEG PA ON PA.NPOLICY=AU.NPOLICY 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT  NIDAPESEG, MAX(NIDAPESEGLOG ) AS NIDAPESEGLOG
                 FROM PV_APESEG_LOG
                 GROUP BY  NIDAPESEG) PLOG1 ON PLOG1.NIDAPESEG=PA.NIDAPESEG
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT NROTRIED, SCOD_ERROR, NDIGIT_VERIF, NIDAPESEG, NIDAPESEGLOG ,DCOMPDATE
                 FROM PV_APESEG_LOG
                 ) PLOG ON PLOG.NIDAPESEG=PA.NIDAPESEG and PLOG.NIDAPESEGLOG=PLOG1.NIDAPESEGLOG
  --  LEFT JOIN PV_FC_ERRORS_APESEG E ON E.SCODEERROR = PLOG.SCOD_ERROR
  --LEFT JOIN PV_FC_ERRORS_APESEG E ON E.SCODEERROR IN REGEXP_SUBSTR(PLOG.SCOD_ERROR,'[^|]+')
  --LEFT JOIN PV_FC_ERRORS_APESEG E ON  E.SCODEERROR IN '('||TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(PLOG.SCOD_ERROR, '|', ','))||')'
    LEFT JOIN PV_FC_ERRORS_APESEG E ON  E.SCODEERROR IN (40622,40605)
    WHERE AU.NPOLICY = 7000015213
   -- AND PLOG.scod_error IN (40622,40605)
   -- AND E.SCODEERROR IN '('||TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(PLOG.SCOD_ERROR, '|', ','))||')'
    GROUP BY  AU.sregist, CL.SCLIENAME,   
      S.SDESCRIPT,
      AU.NPOLICY, 
      AU.npremium,
      AU.SCLIENT, 
      PC.SCLIENAME,
      AU.dstartdate, 
      AU.dexpirdat, 
      AU.NPOLICY,
      PLOG.DCOMPDATE,
      PLOG.SCOD_ERROR, 
      PLOG1.NIDAPESEG, PLOG1.NIDAPESEGLOG, PLOG.NROTRIED, PLOG.SCOD_ERROR, 
      PLOG.NDIGIT_VERIF, PLOG.NIDAPESEG, PLOG.NIDAPESEGLOG ,PLOG.DCOMPDATE
    ORDER BY AU.DCOMPDATE, AU.NPOLICY ;
```

Comment: El problema, según veo, es que incluyes la columna E.SDESERROR por si sola, con el alias DESERROR, pero no la incluyes dentro del `group by`. Elimina esa columna del select, pues entiendo que tu intención es que se concatene la descripción, no?

Answer (score 0):

La cláusula *SELECT* con *GROUP BY* sólo debe contener columnas de agrupamiento ó agregaciones; entiéndase agregación como columnas a las que se les aplica una función de agregación.

Tienes varios detalles, los principales:

- `E.SDESERROR` lo tienes como agrupamiento y como agregado, es como decir: agrupa aquí pero por separado :S. Parece que deberías quitarla del SELECT y dejarla en `xmlaggr()`.
- La columna `CL.SCLIENAME` no tiene agregación y no está como agrupamiento, debería estar en `GROUP BY`.

Una forma de verlo es: Todas las columnas de *GROUP BY* deben estar en el *SELECT* y las que no, deberían estar en una función de agregación como sum(), count(), avg(), min(), max(), etc.